# Como obter a própria instância (this) em um callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
class Cat {
    constructor(name, picture) {    
        this.name = name;
        this.picture = picture;
        this.count = 0;

        // ...

        this.img.click(function () {
            this.count++; // não funciona como eu espero
        });
    }
}
```

Observe a linha `this.img.click`. A partir dela, o `this` passa a ser o `img`, porém dentro do callback eu manipulo o `count` que é do `Cat`.

Não posso usar `this.count++;` como está escrito pois o `this` naquele ponto não se refere mais ao `Cat`.

Como faço para acessar a instância de `Cat` dentro do callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem **4 maneiras** de se fazer isso.

## 1. Guardar uma referência em variável

A primeira é a da [resposta do Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235459/), e consiste em guardar uma referência ao objeto `this` desejado numa variável a que a função tenha acesso. Repito o exemplo do Isac:

```
let obj = this; //criar referencia aqui
this.img.click(function () {
    obj.count++; //usar count através da referencia
});
```

## 2. Criar uma função com `this` fixo

Toda função em JS tem um método [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) que cria uma cópia da função atrelada a um `this` específico. Com esse recurso você poderia fazer assim:

```
const incrementar = function() {
    this.count++
};
this.img.click(incrementar.bind(this));
```

## 3. Arrow functions

As *arrow functions* não possuem contexto/`this` próprio, e permitem algo mais próximo do seu código original:

```
this.img.click( () => this.count++ );
```

## 4. Implementando `EventListener`

Esse método é pouco conhecido, mas seu objeto pode escutar e tratar eventos internamente, se implementar a [interface `EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener). Um exemplo baseado no seu:

```
class MyCounter {

    constructor() {    
        this.count = 0;
        this.btn = document.querySelector('#some-button');

        // Repare que passamos this em vez de uma função
        this.btn.addEventListener('click', this, false);
    }

    incrementa() {
       this.count++;
    }

    // Implementa a interface EventListener
    handleEvent(e) {
       if(e.type === 'click') {
          this.incrementa();
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode criar uma referencia para o objeto em si que depois usa dentro do callback:

```
class Cat {
    constructor(name, picture) {    
        this.name = name;
        this.picture = picture;
        this.count = 0;

        // ...
        let obj = this; //criar referencia aqui
        this.img.click(function () {
            obj.count++; //usar count através da referencia
        });
    }
}
```